# Doesn't $ sign in vim force you to leave home row? Is there a default alternative?

Tags: vim, keyboard, key-bindings, eol

I am an emacs user and I'm trying to learn some vim to see if I may prefer it. 
One of my main issues is the $ sign for end of line. I thought that the main principal in vim was to stay on the home row however the $ sign forces me off it. Is there a default alternative? I know I can remap it but I prefer using editor defaults whenever possible.

Comment: There are only so many characters that can be typed from the home row. You can't do everything from there.

Comment: I am going to go out on a limb here but you might be interested in `A` to start insert mode at the end of the line. See `:h A`. `I` start insert mode at the start of the line. See `:h I`

Comment: @PeterRincker I thought of `A` as OP's "alternative" too, but it needs `ESC`, still left home row. :-(

Comment: @Kent, I see your `<esc>` and raise you `<c-[>` which is closer. Use `inoremap jk <esc>` if you really want to stay on the home row. However one must learn to use `<esc>` (or equivalent) if they are going to use Vim. There is now way around this

Comment: "I thought that the main principal in vim was to stay on the home row" First, nothing in Vim is designed with the home row in mind. Second, the home row only contains 12 keys, which would not be nearly enough even for nano.

Answer (score 2):

Keys on home row won't do anything for you. `hjkl` are there, and they are handy because we need them so often to navigate in buffer. Except for those four keys, there are still `) w b e ]...`, they are very often used as well, but as you can see they are not on home row either.

`^ and $` (BOL, EOL) are the same, I *guess* the two keys were chosen because kind of convention. in Regex, `^ and $` indicate BOL and EOL.

We have more than 100 (well mine has 60) keys on our keyboard, we cannot rely on only 10 keys to do all the work.

I suggest you trying to live with those default keys, if it is not possible, you can create mapping for the `$` after all.

Answer (score 1):

I'll second @Kent's opinion: Though it's certainly convenient and effective that the frequently used `hjkl` motions are all on the home row, there's no exclusiveness to it. In fact, many Vim beginners focus to much on those basic navigation commands, and don't fully utilize the power of the other motions like `w` / `W`, `f` / `t`.

As has been written many times before, Vim's commands form a wonderfully precise and concise language. In my opinion, you get most of the efficiency from avoiding the separate cursor keys (which other editors force you to use, or an even worse switch over to the mouse). That's what's meant by *vi / Vim keeps your fingers on the home row*: its commands and motions are all accessible through the basic keys around the home row, there's no use for the extended keyboard keys like the cursor block or numeric keypad, or mouse. If you're a touch typist, you'll know that there's a dramatic difference between those; the difference between home row and adjacent rows is much less.